# google api xml EURUSD

Tags: xml, api, euro

I saw that you can pull `xml` quotes on stocks from the Google API like this:
http://www.google.com/ig/api?stock=GOOG

Is it possible to get Euro USD xml the same way?

This is the site, but need the xml: http://www.google.com/finance?q=EURUSD

I'd probably have to give another parameter than "stock" but I couldn't find any information on that.

Comment: Side note - The Google Finance API is being deprecated and will shut down in October 2012, so you may want to find a different API anyway.